# Transitive-intransitive pairs with different readings

Tags: transitivity, multiple-readings

Transitive-intransitive pairs are common in Japanese. But in general the reading of the *kanji* is the same. I know of two exceptions: 出す{だす}-出る{でる} and 入れる{いれる}-入る{はいる}. Are there more?

Comment: Interesting question but could you give more specific criteria? For example, do you expect 教【おそ】わる and 教【おし】える in your list?

Comment: @broccoliforest If there are few verbs even with loose criteria then no need to get finicky. But if the list can be long, then perhaps a typology will arise. I honestly don't know the answer to your question because I don't know the answer to mine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many possible ways to demarcate your question's scope, but if we focus on *pairs whose morae until the shorter kanji coverage ends are different* (based on the current orthography), the number is quite limited.

- **入【はい】る** (*it.*) : **入【い】れる** (*t.*)
  The intransitive is a suppletion from はいいる "sneak in".
- **出【で】る** : **出【だ】す**
  The pair lost their initial mora; in Classical Japanese they were いでる and いだす.
- **消【き】える** : **消【け】す**
  Already different since the earliest appearance (きゆ vs. けつ).
- **教【おそ】わる** : **教【おし】える**
  The intransitive is post-Classical; perhaps the influence of 襲う "inherit"?
- **出来【でき】る** : **出来【でか】す**
  A leveled conjugation of Classical いでく and its transitive by analogy.
- **干【ひ】る** : **干【ほ】す**
  The intransitive is almost obsolete but nevertheless in 常用漢字表 because of its numerous compounds.
- [Added] **陥【おちい】る** : **陥【おとしい】れる**
  The sole paired compound verbs that let both elements alter (落ちる + 入【い】る vs 落とす + 入れる) and have a single kanji.

The lengthy criterion above is to exclude such pairs that the kanji is allowed to span in unequal length under the orthography, which are not very rare:

> 終【おわ】る (also 終わる) : 終【お】える / 冷【ひ】える : 冷【ひや】す (also 冷やす) / 泊【とま】る (also 泊まる) : 泊【と】める / 変【かわ】る (also 変わる) : 変【か】える etc.

And even:

> 座【すわ】る : 据【す】える / 怖【お】じる : 脅【おど】す etc.

Comment: For きゆ・けす, the even older form might be く, as possibly indicated by [万葉集 poem 4024](http://jti.lib.virginia.edu/japanese/manyoshu/Man17Yo.html#4024): 「立山【たちやま】の雪【ゆき】し消【く】らしも」.  Thus, きゆ would represent 上二段 + spontaneous ゆ, and けす would represent 下二段 + transitive / causative す.  Notably, instances in the 万葉集 of 消 read as け are analyzed as 上代特殊仮名遣い as having the vowel value //e₂//, which is [reconstructed by some as possibly //we//](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_Japanese#Vowels), aligning with a potential derivation as //ku// + //e// → //ke₂//.  I cannot find 消 read as き in the 万葉集, however.

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi Interesting, thank you for your input. Yes, 消ゆ seems certainly newer somehow.

Comment: 陥 (おちいる) vs 陥 (おとしいれる) is interesting (although transparent). I hadn't come across the transitive before.

Comment: @jogloran That means you're lucky that you've not 陥る into a situation someone 陥れる you :D