# Where does the -a stem come from with auxiliary-constructed transitive/intransitive verb pairs if the base verb is a 二段活用 (or カ行変格活用)?

Tags: verbs, etymology, transitivity, auxiliaries, old-japanese

It seems to be generally understood that transitive/intransitive verb pairs, when they are not a 四段活用 and a 二段活用 that share the same 終止形, were created by taking a base verb, whether transitive or intransitive, and adding an Old Japanese auxiliary - す for transitivity, and る or ゆ for intransitivity - to the 未然形 to form the verb of opposite transitivity. For example, [減]{へ}る (intransitive) + す = [減]{へ}らす (transitive).

But something confuses me - since auxiliaries like す、る、ゆ、ふ、etc. only attach to the 未然形, what is the deal with 二段活用 verbs? For example, [覚]{さ}む is a 下二段活用 intransitive verb, and [覚]{さ}ます is its transitive variant.

Where does this -a stem in [覚]{さ}ます come from? The 未然形 of [覚]{さ}む is [覚]{さ}め, not [覚]{さ}ま like if it were a 四段活用. Would it not logically be [覚]{さ}めす instead? [上]{あ}ぐ becomes [上]{あ}がる, [満]{み}つ becomes [満]{み}たす - all of these are 二段活用 verbs, which do not feature an -a stem in their 未然形, yet the opposite transitivity uses an -a stem. What is the reason for this?

This also seems to appear for カ行変格活用 verbs as well, as [出]{で}[来]{き}る -> [出]{で}[来]{か}す instead of でこす.

According to the Wiktionary etymology of あぢさはふ:

> The initial adi is likely from the 䳑鴨 (ajigamo, “Baikal teal”),[1] while the derivation of sapapu is unknown.
>
> One theory states from 障ふ (sapu), basis for modern 障える (saeru, “to hinder, interrupt”, transtitive) and 障わる (sawaru, “to disturb, harm”, intransitive). This is problematic as sapu is a 下二段活用 (shimo nidan katsuyō, “lower bigrade conjugation”) verb and not a 四段活用 (yodan katsuyō, “quadrigrade conjugation”) verb required for a 未然形 (mizenkei, “irrealis form”) ending in -a.

This seems to suggest that 二段活用 verbs cannot simply swap to an -a stem when an auxiliary is added (here being ふ).

There are also some verb pairs where both the intransitive and transitive verbs have auxiliaries on a non-verbal-未然形 root, like [外]{はづ}す and [外]{はづ}る, and there are also some curiosities like [消]{け}す and [消]{き}ゆ where the roots are not the same vowel. What is the reason for this as well?

Comment: There was a discussion about the 消つ/消ゆ case that associates it with pre-Old contraction. https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/66436/transitive-intransitive-pairs-with-different-readings/66451#comment114131_66451

Comment: @brokenlaptop thanks, also I just looked at the page and realized that [出]{で}[来]{か}す is another instance of the -a stem somehow appearing, since 未然形 of く is こ. So it's not just 二段活用, it's カ行変格活用 too... interesting. Though a later か -> こ transition could be likely since this has been seen countless times, I'm not sure and don't want to make any assumptions

Comment: I find a paper about it but I don't have time to write a summary right now. So I put the link here. If I can take some time, I'll write the summary as an answer. (or if there is someone who has read this article and write answer, it's grateful)https://kpu.repo.nii.ac.jp/?action=repository_uri&item_id=4083&file_id=19&file_no=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My major is not linguistics but I found some interesting references for you.

Aoki[1] introduces a few types of classification of transitive/intransitive verbs in Japanese.

The first classification is written by Kuginuki[2]. It says there are 3 patterns of transitive/intransitive verb pairs.

1. Depending on the type of conjugation (第Ⅰ群形式)

   > 知る (四段活用 is an intransitive verb and 下二段活用 is a transitive verb) 
   > 切る (下二段活用 is an intransitive verb and 四段活用 is a transitive verb)
2. Depending on the termination of a word (第Ⅱ群形式)

   > 成る (intransitive), 成す (transitive) 
   > 寄る (intransitive), 寄す (transitive)
3. Depending on the additional stem and additional termination of a word (第Ⅲ群形式)

   > 明く (intransitive), 明かす (transitive) 
   > 上ぐ (transitive), 上がる (intransitive)

The second classification is written by Okutsu[3].

1. Transitivization (from intransitive to transitive)

   > 乾く → 乾かす 
   > 落ちる → 落とす
2. Intransitivization (from transitive to intransitive)

   > まげる → まがる 
   > はさむ → はさまる
3. Polarization (from some common element to transitive or intransitive verb)

   > 帰る → 帰す 
   > アク → アケル

Kageyama[4] follows the second classification. And in [4], transitivization is classified into two patterns:

1. intransitive verb + -e- → transitive verb

   > 割る (waru) → 割れる (wareru) 
   > 抜く (nuku) → 抜ける (nukeru)
2. intransitive verb + -ar- → transitive verb

   > 植える (ueru) → 植わる (uwaru) 
   > 集める (atsumeru) → 集まる (atsumaru)

and also intransitivization is classified into two:

1. transitive verb + -e- → intransitive verb

   > 建つ (tatsu) → 建てる (tateru) 
   > 進む (susumu) → 進める (susumeru)
2. transitive verb + -as- or -os- → intransitive verb

   > 鳴る (naru) → 鳴らす (narasu) 
   > 枯れる (kareru) → 枯らす (karasu) 
   > 起きる (okiru) → 起こす (okosu)

Aoki[1] summarizes the above as follows:

In 第Ⅰ群形式, 下二段活用 verb is derived from 四段活用動詞. And 第Ⅲ群形式 is derived from 第Ⅱ群形式.

And Aoki also says that auxiliaries る and す are derived from these suffixes.

So I personally think the matter of transitive/intransitive verbs has some relationship with auxiliaries but it seems a bit different from the way you think.

[1] AOKI Hiroshi, "On the relationship of paired yodan-shimonidan conjugation" in 京都府立大学学術報告(人文・社会), vol.53, Dec 2001, Available:https://kpu.repo.nii.ac.jp/?action=pages_view_main&active_action=repository_view_main_item_detail&item_id=4083&item_no=1&page_id=13&block_id=17 [Accessed Jul. 13, 2021]

[2] KUGINUKI Tooru, "古代日本語の形態変化", 1996, 和泉書院, Available:https://nagoya.repo.nii.ac.jp/records/14721 [Accessed Jul. 13, 2021]

[3] OKUTSU Keiichirō, "自動化・他動化および両極化転形ー自・他動詞の対応" in 『国語学』第70集, Sep. 30, 1967, Available:https://bibdb.ninjal.ac.jp/SJL/view.php?h_id=0700460660 [Accessed Jul. 13, 2021]

[4] KAGEYAMA Tarō, "動詞意味論－言語と認知の接点―",1996, くろしお出版, No PDF (I borrowed this book from a library)

Comment: Sorry for the late response. So it seems like, possibly, instead of a simple auxiliary that goes onto a certain base (未然形), it's more like the ク語法 situation where the suffix [所]{あく} blended into the 連体形, causing the -a- to appear everywhere regardless of the paradigm. Just pure speculation, but the -ar- intransitivation could possibly be from 終止形 + [有]{あ}る? Though あり was a ラ変... Regardless, thanks. It seems like this matter probably needs more looking into. [Speculation about  /a/ ↔ /o/ alternation](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/82923/39722) might apply to the -as-/-os-.